# apache make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8989

Tags: apache

When I execute:

```
service httpd start,
```

I get this error

```
httpd：(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8989
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8989
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

In httpd.conf, it is `Listen 8989`. When I change to `Listen *:8989`, it works. Why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

something is using port 8989. May be a previous instance of Apache itself.

In your shell/cmd enter

Windows: (you may need to run as administrator)

```
netstat -anb
```

Linux:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

By the way, do you have multiple `Listen` directive in `httpd.conf`? make sure you have one.